# Laravel loading error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, laravel

When I tried to access my laravel after successfull updation, instead of the default page it shows an error in the webpage.

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I have tried some fixes like this,

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini’: File exists
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did you install mcrypt? And have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10

Comment: @RonniSkansing The solution of the above commented question is already done, thats why it's giving error in second time.

Comment: @hakre I am already installed it using apt and enabled it.

Comment: @harke My question is am already installed, enabled, created symbolic link for mcrypt. Then again why the laravel web page shows the mcrypt error?

Comment: @hakre Do you have any solution for me?

Comment: Why did you do `sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini`? It looks wrong to me, perhaps you can explain.

Comment: @hakre In this command I am creating a symbolic link between the first file and second file. Because in ubuntu some php versions will look for this file. It was the correct solution which is worked in my Ubuntu 13.10 also. But it didn't worked in Ubuntu 14.04. It may be the problem with Ubuntu or PHP version.

Comment: According to the message the file is already there, so it would not need any linking. So if I may ask again: If the file is already there, why did you link it?

Comment: No, actually the file was not there in first time. When I executed the command it's created.When a tried to execute again it shows the error. The reason to post that in my question is to inform you that I already tried the solution and the file is there.

Comment: Which PHP SAPI are you using with the webserver? What does `php -i` on the commandline output about mcrypt?

Comment: I can't see anything related to mcrypt here.

Comment: run this command in terminal  
php -m and see if mcrypt is in list or not

Comment: @user2686338 I can see that the mcrypt in the list.

Comment: I had the same problem when upgrading to 14.04, so I execute Laravel artisan commands `./artisan serve --port=8001` in my project folder.

Comment: @Razor Thanks, it's working with ``artisan serve`` command. But I am not satisfied with this option. Please share when you got the correct solution.

Comment: @hakre ``php --ini`` gives this list ``Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-memcached.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- PHP version: PHP 5.5.9
- Ubuntu: 14.04

After a lot of trial and error and searching around, this is what I discovered.

**getting artisan command working**

i did a lot of trial and error so each time i run the php5enmod command before, i had error messages. but on fresh install there was no error messages. after this step i got artisan command working

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo apt-get purge php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

**fixing the browser error**

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

add the following line under the dynamically compiled extensions section of php ini

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

restart the apache server, purge the laravel cache and everything working.

Comment: Purging the old php5-mcrypt, reinstalling and running php5enmod solved for me.
This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Again no luck, it's shows ``Mcrypt PHP extension required``

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the mcrypt library seems to be here : /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so

So I just created a new file mcrypt.ini in /etc/php5/mods-available and add:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Then I execute `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` and reload apache

Comment: I am already have this mcrypt.ini file here and also tried by adding full path to the ``so`` file in the ``ini``, but no luck.

Comment: When you execute `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`, you got errors or it's return to the next line (prompt)?

Comment: It's going to next line without any errors.

Comment: And of course, you did restart apache after the change right?

Answer (score 0):

This StackOverflow answer may be what you need: ["laravel can't find mcrypt extension in php 5.5"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921108).

All I was missing was `sudo php5enmod mcrypt; sudo service apache2 restart`, but if that hasn't worked for you, the link suggests this:

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If there are any other mcrypt ini files in `/etc/php5/mods-available/`, you may want to consider removing those as well. Let `php5enmod` do its job & handle that side of things.

Comment: This one also not working, after removing the available ini file,  the php5enmod command shows this warning ``WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php5/mods-available`` and it's not creating new ini here.